# tomcat:access to outsider html page

Tags: jsf, tomcat

I have html reports saved to disk, I want to display these files in my Jsf application deployed under tomcat 6.
Is it possible to configure Tomcat to include these files with the context of my web application

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could configure another context (in server.xml) pointing to the folder where your reports are, then link to them this way.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply.
could you clarify a bit about how I use this approach?
how to declare a new context? and how to access these pages from my jsf web application?